# The Sketchup Import Add On in blender does not enable in Blender v2.93

Tags: add-on, import

I downloaded the zip file from the [github link](https://github.com/arindam-m/pyslapi/releases/tag/0.21) and installed the Add On the usual way:

[image]

[image]

[image]

However when I navigate to the Add On option and click on the checkbox, it does not enable:

[image]

Could anyone tell me if I am missing something? All the other addons seem to work just fine its just this one that I am having issues with.

Answer (score 1):

Your link points to a previous version. The version for Blender 2.93 is [here](https://github.com/arindam-m/pyslapi/releases/tag/v0.23.0).
[image]